# Why can't I append just one value in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

This is part of a project I am working on, my question is that I don't know why are the values getting assigned to all the keys, when I just want to append them to the item with the key 'A', is there maybe another way to think it, I will need to append lists, creating a big list of lists per key.

```
speakers = ['A','B']
fragments = dict.fromkeys(speakers,[])
TAGS = ['A', ['121560', '124390']]
fragments[TAGS[0]].append(list(map(int,TAGS[1])))
print(fragments)
```

```
{'A': [[121560, 124390]], 'B': [[121560, 124390]]}
```

I need to obtain:
`{'A': [[121560, 124390]], 'B': []}`

And if I do again: 
`fragments[TAGS[0]].append(list(map(int,TAGS[1])))`

Then I should get:
`{'A': [[121560, 124390],[121560, 124390]], 'B': []}`

Thank you!

Comment: I solved it by using:
```fragments = {i:[] for i in speakers}```
Like Alexander and Tomeriko said, they were sharing memory, so the value replicated to all the keys within the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a variant of the mutable default argument question: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

The problem is that you two lists for `A` and `B` are actually one and the same!

```
>>> id(fragments['A']) is id(fragments['B'])
True  # They both point to the same list object in memory.
```

One solution is to use a dictionary comprehension to instantiate your dictionary with null lists.

```
fragments = {k: list() for k in speakers}
```

Another solution would be to use `defaultdict` with a list as the default factory.

```
from collections import defaultdict

fragments = defaultdict(list)
```

Comment: this really doesn't have anything to do with mutable default arguments. There is nothing in the *language* preventing `dict.fromkeys` from making a copy of that object, it simply doesn't.

Comment: Also note, `id(<some expression>) == id(<some expression>)` can give you misleading results if you don't understand, for example, consider `id([]) == id([])`. This will often return `True`, although, those are two different `list` objects being created. It is always best practice to use `<some expression> is <some expression>`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I disagree with your first point, as `fromkeys` sets the value of each key to the single argument passed to `value`, a single list object in this case. This case is similar to the mutable default argument case which also gets passed a single mutable object which gets shared by instances of the object.

Comment: But it *doesn't involve default values*. I mean, you're right that it is the same root cause, that an object is re-used, but the same could be said about `x = []; y = []; x.append('foo')`. But if you *knew and understood* how default arguments work, that still doesn't tell you why `dict.fromkeys` works that way, because it isn't dealing with a default value.

Comment: I didn't say the issue was exactly the same, I said it was a variant.  The OP was expecting separate list objects for each key but instead got the same one because of how the `fromkeys` constructor was called. The OP didn't realize that this caused the same list object to be allocated as the value to each key.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is exactly the [documentation of `fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> [fromkeys()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) is a class method that returns a new dictionary. *value*
>   defaults to `None`. All of the values refer to just a single instance,
>   so it generally **doesn’t make sense for *value* to be a mutable object
>   such as an empty list**. To get distinct values, use a [dict
>   comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dict) instead.